# Can i set cronjob for controller action in magento?

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.8

I created my module and that has config.xml and controller. In that i need to setup cron job for the action in controller named as testAction().Anyone pls help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Why don't you create an event observer?

Comment: have to.. but i don't know how to change coding according to that.

Comment: You can use wget to run your controller in cron.

Comment: but in my config file i setup my crontab as like
    `<config>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <my_cron>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>mymodule/observer::doSomething</model>
                </run>
            </my_cron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>`.. Don't want to edit this??

Answer (score 0):

set observer method then redirect from observer method

```
$response1 = $observer->getResponse(); 

$url = 'http://www.website.com/';
$response1->setRedirect($url);
```

OR you can check this

```
$observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url','http://www.google.com/');
```